How to read accented letters from terminal in Java?
I have the following Java snippet:
System.out.print("What is the first name of the Hungarian poet Petőfi? ");
String correctAnswer = "Sándor";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String answer = sc.next();
sc.close();
if (correctAnswer.equals(answer)) {
    System.out.println("Correct!");
} else {
    System.out.println("The answer (" + answer + ") is incorrect, the correct answer is " + correctAnswer);
}

This works fine in Eclipse, but does not work in Windows terminal: even though I enter the correct answer Sándor, the comparison fails. This is how it looks like in Eclipse:
What is the first name of the Hungarian poet Petőfi? Sándor
Correct!

The same from command line:
What is the first name of the Hungarian poet Petőfi? Sándor
The answer (S?ndor) is incorrect, the correct answer is Sándor

What I tried without success are the following:

CHCP 65001 (to change code page to UTF-8): this is needed only if the word Petőfi is incorrectly displayed, but does not help the input.
[Console]::InputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding
Passing StandardCharsets.UTF_8 or "UTF-8" to Scanner.
Using InputStreamReader (with and without passing the encoding) instead of Scanner.
Passing -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 command line parameter.
Adding line System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");
Using PowerShell instead of cmd

I double-checked: the encoding of the Java source file is UTF-8.
When converting to bytes (Arrays.toString(input.getBytes())) I experience the following:

By default the non-accented letters get their normal ASCII codes. The accented letters have 3 bytes length, all negative values. Before code page change the bytes of Sándor is this: [83, -17, -65, -67, 110, 100, 111, 114].
When the code page is changed to UTF-8, then the non-accented letters remain the same, while the accented ones all become one character length 0. After code page change the bytes are this: [83, 0, 110, 100, 111, 114].
The same in Eclipse: [83, -61, -95, 110, 100, 111, 114]
The String Sándor is actually encoded in Java like this: [83, -61, -95, 110, 100, 111, 114]

So to narrow down to the letter á we have the following:

Java encodes it as C3 A1 which is "Latin Small Letter A With Acute" according to https://www.charset.org/utf-8.
After input this is encoded like EF BF BD which is the � "Replacement Character" according to https://www.charset.org/utf-8/66.
After CHCP 65001 change it is encoded as 0.

It works in Git Bash, but the letter ő (and all the other accented characters, not just this one) is incorrectly displayed in that terminal:
What is the first name of the Hungarian poet Pet▒fi? Sándor
Correct!

It is strange that even the comparison works, and entering the accented characters looks fine, repeated displaying the same does not work:
What is the first name of the Hungarian poet Pet▒fi? Péter
The answer (P▒ter) is incorrect, the correct answer is S▒ndor

The following helped in Windows terminal:
Console console = System.console();
String answer = console.readLine();

But this does not work in Eclipse:
What is the first name of the Hungarian poet Petőfi? Sándor
The answer (SĂˇndor) is incorrect, the correct answer is Sándor

UPDATE: it seems it depends on the system settings. I have 2 laptops, one of Hungarian and the other of English settings.

The Hungarian one works with System.console() in terminal, and the new Scanner(System.in) works in Eclipse. However, in Eclipse it works incorrectly, even if I change the encoding in Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace.
In the English version I did not find any working option in terminal: either the output (like the letter ő) is incorrect or the comparison fails. And when trying to use the System.console() approach, then it throws NullPointerException being the console null. (That Eclipse version is 2023-12; I did not try the latest one there.)

My Java version is 22.0.2, but the problem does not seem version-specific.
As a cross-check I tried the same in Python, and it works fine both in the Windows terminal and also in IDE without any problem:
answer = input('What is the first name of the Hungarian poet Petőfi? ')
correct_answer = 'Sándor'
if answer == correct_answer:
    print('Correct')
else:
    print('The answer (' + answer + ') is incorrect, the correct answer is ' + correct_answer)

So my question is: how to make it work? Is there an universal solution which works in both Windows terminal and Eclipse?

Have you ever set CHCP 65001 to Cmd like chcp 65001 ?

Maybe you need to configure the terminal itself to use UTF-8? Java 22 should use UTF-8 by default (though you could try changing that to whatever encoding Windows likes to use).

CHCP 65001 is the first I tried, see the description.

Note that the eclipse console view has a configurable encoding, too. You can check it in the corresponding Run Configuration (usually it inherits eclipse's file encoding).

Try in Powershell, but run this first [Console]::InputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding  Make sure your code encoding is UTF-8 and not some 7/8 bit monstrosity

[Console]::InputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding did not help.
The length is correct, but after changing the character set in the terminal, and converting the input to bytes, the accented letters become all 0.

converting the input to bytes How do you do that?

Also, what does this print? System.out.println(java.util.HexFormat.ofDelimiter(" ").formatHex(correctAnswer.getBytes()));

converting the input to bytes How do you do that?
answer.getBytes()
Also, what does this print?
53 c3 a1 6e 64 6f 72
Here the c3 a1 part is the letter á.
I updated the original description with the (decimal) bytes in various cases.

That's all promising. I would try to cut the IDE out of the picture for the moment and compile and run in Powershell.

This question is similar to: Eclipse character encoding. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I was able to get this to work in a regular Command window, by saving the file as UTF-8, using javac -encoding UTF-8, and by doing chcp 65001 before running.  I did not need to specify any system properties or encodings in the java command.

Sigh. 12 comments and nobody with the right answer. The right answer is: new Scanner(System.in) is broken. It's herculean to try to teach the java community this. See my answer. Use console, use new Scanner(System.console().reader()), pray the java.io.IO preview feature is out of preview in JDK24, but please stop coming up with ridiculous workarounds to preserve new Scanner(System.in); terminate that code on sight instead.

@JosefZ: my problem is not about Eclipse but about Windows command line. This makes the difference.

@rzwitserloot Note that the OP specifically asked for it to work with both Eclipse and cmd and Console didn't seem to work with Eclipse.

@rzwitserloot Using new Scanner(System.console().reader())  the input does not show up, but it works. On the other hand it does not work with Eclipse with default settings.

new Scanner(System.console().reader()) Not sure why you wouldn't just use the Console directly

"And when trying to use the System.console() approach, then it throws NullPointerException being the console null." - Are you using an older Java version on that device?

@dan1st I am using 2 laptops, one having English settings + Java 21 + Eclipse 2023-12, while the other having Hungarian settings + Java 22 + Eclipse 2024-06. In the first one the System.console() approach works from command line (with incorrect displaying but correct reading), and it is null in Eclipse, and that throws NPE. With the other it works form command line, the default settings display the accented characters correctly, but from Eclipse the character encoding of reading the input is incorrect.

Yes, System.console() was changed in JDK 22 to not return null.

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in, System.out.charset());

This solution works with Java 18+. This works both in Eclipse with default settings and in Windows command prompt having code page 852. Checking the code page:
chcp

Changing it to 852:
chcp 852

Thanks for everyone who helped reaching the solution!

{ 83, -96, 110, 100, 111, 114 } should have been your output with that encoding. More rational would be new Scanner(System.in, System.in.charset());

Logically thinking yes, but actually it is [83, -61, -95, 110, 100, 111, 114]. I don't know the reason. System.in.charset() does not exist.

Sorry, you're right about System.in

Anytime you go from bytes to chars or vice versa, a charset encoding is applied. And in this seemingly trivial case, there are tens of conversions going on. They all have to use the right encoding or you end up exactly where you are. And then there's unicode shenanigans on top!
So let's go through all this.
Your source file
Step a1: Typing and saving
You write your source file in some editor. That editor is surely not a hex editor so when you click 'save', the editor needs to apply conversion because files are sack of bytes; it is not possible to store characters in them at all (thus, the need to encode them using some charset encoding). You mentioned that the editor is 'configured to be UTF-8', so presumably then UTF-8 is being applied.
Step a2: Compiling
When you run javac (or you run ant or mvn or gradle or whatnot; your build script), javac reads the file from disk and treats it as characters. Which is obviously impossible - files are bytes, not characters. So, javac itself also converts - it converts those bytes back to characters first, then parses the contents. Which means a charset encoding is applied! Which one? Who knows! Best make it  clear by telling javac what to use. Use -charset UTF-8 equivalent, or hunt around the manual of your build tool to figure out how to tell it to tell javac to apply UTF-8.
Step a3: Writing the class file
We dodge the bullet here; java stores strings in class files in a way that charset encoding cannot cause any issues. There is no need to, or in fact any way to, tell javac to output a certain charset encoding; it simply doesn't apply here. Phew. One less conversion to worry about.
Result
If you did it correctly, the actual characters Sándor should be encoded in your compiled class file. If this step failed, the game is lost - you're not going to tell the user they entered the right name unless the journey from the user's brain to your java code happens to make the exact same conversion mistakes as you did when writing and compiling your source file.
The user
Step b1: Typing into the terminal
The user enters the key or key combination that appears to produce á, but, the terminal also works entirely in bytes. System.in, System.out, and System.err are byte based. So, the user enters that character but it is turned into bytes immediately, they are (or rather, the keycodes emitted by the USB controller of the keyboard) the System.in equivalent to the terminal process which is an app just like any other.
Which encoding is applied? Who knows! Check your OS manual. On windows it is usually not UTF-8.
So, keycodes from keyboard go in, charset encoding is applied, bytes come out and are piped to cmd.exe or whatever app is showing you a black box with monospace text. That's not the OS. That's just an application.
Step b2: Terminal rendering
The terminal receives the bytes that came out of the process of converting keycodes into chars and then those chars into bytes. The 'terminal mode' is such that these bytes are echoed (they are displayed), and you can't display bytes, so, the terminal immediately goes right back and converts back to characters just so it can tell the font system which glyph to show. It's technically not the same thing - it is possible but somewhat unlikely that the process in step b1 uses one charset encoding and b2 uses another. It's all got absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with java at any rate; it's OS and terminal settings. If, just on the C:\> prompt, you type á and you see á, then b1 and b2 are likely in alignment (or at least, whatever encodings they use end up at the same way to encode/decode á). That does not mean it's UTF-8. All it means is: It's some encoding that has a way to encode á. Which may well be the ISO-8859 variant for Hungary; there are many encodings that are not at all compatible with UTF-8 that have á in it.
Step b3: Send it to the java process.
The bytes that you send to the systemin of your cmd.exe are relayed verbatim (or not? Who knows! You'd have to ask microsoft, cmd.exe is not open source so I can't check) to the process that cmd.exe spawned when you typed java YourClass, and, yes, you guessed it, these are in byte form. Nothing happens here (probably) - whatever the bytes were that you ended up at in step b1 are sent unchanged to the java process.
Step b4: Java needs to read it.
These bytes arrive at System.in and java needs to turn that back into characters because while System.in is definitely bytes, Scanner is characters. So in new Scanner(System.in) you are applying a charset encoding, silently.
This gets us to an ugly truth: Scanner is bad, not meant for keyboard input, and definitely should not be used like this. 1
Unfortunately, tens of thousands of stack overflow answers, and thousands of tutorials act like Scanner is for keyboard input, and they are all wrong. It's for tokenizing char-based streams, and treating keyboard input as that is doubly wrong. It's [A] not really tokenized (or if it is, delimited by enter presses and not spaces, and yet scanner by default tokenizes on spaces, and no tutorial I know of tells you to fix that by calling .useDelimiter("\\R") which at least solves one of the two major disconnects between Scanner and 'terminal keyboard input'), and [B] System.in is bytes, not chars.
Whatever charset new Scanner(System.in) picked, if it 'picked wrong' (it did not pick the same one steps b1 and b2 picked), you end up with this problem.
This is likely where your problem lies.
Without knowing how you set up your system exactly it's not possible to be sure of that; hence the full explanation so, if fixing b4 doesn't help, you know where to investigate next.
Fixing b4
Option 1: java.io.IO
It's a preview feature, so you can't use this yet / you need java23 and --enable-preview, but the java.io.IO class is the right tool (where new Scanner(System.in), despite those million tutorials, is not).
Option 2: java.io.Console
This one you can just use, it's been part of java for a while:
Console console = System.console();
String answer = console.readLine();
if (answer.equals("Sándor")) ....

Unfortunately, I guess because everyone is hypnotized by Scanner for some reason, various eclipse 'console' implementations don't support it at all.
Option 3: Actually 'fix' scanner
Via JEP 400, starting with Java18, the default charset encoding is always UTF-8 regardless of what the underlying platform's actual default encoding is.
This means new Scanner(System.in) is very very wrong, and will mess up all non-ASCII chars on windows and any other system that doesn't use UTF-8 as system default, starting in that release.
You can tell a JVM on bootup not to do that (with java -Dfile.encoding=COMPAT) but that really isn't the best way to go about it. Starting in JDK18 this will set things right:
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in, System.getProperty("native.encoding"));

This avoids calling System.console() which thus avoids issues with consoles-in-editors not supporting that. However, that property does not exist in JDK releases before 18, so to write something that works everywhere, you'd write:
String nativeEncoding = System.getProperty("native.encoding", System.getProperty("file.encoding"));

Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in, nativeEncoding);

Quite a mouthful. But it is the price to pay if you want to use the outdated 'make a scanner of system in' style in a way that works on all JDK releases, from 8 to 23.
Unicode shenanigans
Entirely separate from all of the above, 'compare 2 strings' when unicode is involved is a complex beast in any case. Various different unicode values have an identical glyph in most fonts. For example, There's this string: "IJsselmeer" which is how your average dutch person would type the name of that big lake thing in the middle that used to be an ocean. However, there's also "Ĳsselmeer". Which should look identical. If it doesn't your font is weird. But those are not the same; one uses a capital I followed by a capital J. The other uses the capital Ĳ digraph symbol. You may have heard about 'unicode normalization' which does not fix this. It is decidedly non-trivial to answer the question: "Do these 2 strings appear the same to the user", let alone "were they intended to mean the same thing?" - that generally requires mind reading which computers cannot do.
I wouldn't be surprised if the unicode table contains tens of symbols that all look exactly like á. Languages tend to get their own full alphabet and á is in lots of em. So, if that's what's happening (the user is typing a different thing that also looks like á than what you wrote in your source file), then nothing is going to help you.

[1] In case you feel like disagreeing with this statement, note that e.g. the javadoc of Scanner itself, in recent JDK releases, knows about this problem and goes out of its way to avoid suggesting new Scanner(System.in). Perhaps check this for yourself - new Scanner(System.console().reader()) is as far as things go.

Thank you for your detailed explanation! Unfortunately neither of your suggestions solved the problem. On the other hand I somewhat extended the description by adding the bytes it read. I narrowed down the problem to the following.
The letter á is encoded in Java to C3 A1, which is "Latin Small Letter A With Acute" per definition.
The letter á is encoded EF BF BD in Windows terminal by default, which is "Replacement Character" per definition.
If the code page is changed to 65001, then it is simply encoded as 00, which is an obvious error.

Keep in mind that Windows uses a different encoding in the console than in the rest of the UI. So System.getProperty("native.encoding") does not give you the right console encoding. With Java 18+ you can try Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in, System.out.charset());, as the standard output will be initialized to the console’s encoding, which would also be the right one to read from the console. Alternatively, you could use System.console().charset(), introduced in Java 17, but this answer already mentions it, it doesn’t work inside Eclipse, as Eclipse doesn’t initialize the console.

Since java.io.IO is merely a wrapper around System.console(), for the ease of use in single-source files, it doesn’t help.

The letter á is encoded in Java to C3 A1, which is "Latin Small Letter A With Acute" per definition. - that is not correct, @CsabaFaragó - The byte sequence 0xC3 0xA1 is what happens when you store the unicode symbol "Latin Small letter A with Acute" in UTF-8. THe distinction is very very important. EF BF BD is the end result of some longwinded process that ends up converting a character first to 'oh crap we cannot represent it' and then that to unicode.

It sounds like your windows setup is such that the charset encoding used in the terminal is not capable of representing á, in which case, you've just lost the game at that point and all you can do is fix that. However, if you see á, then that would appear to indicate whatever the terminal is using for charset encoding, it can represent that symbol, thus something else is going on. Once 0xEF 0xBF 0xBF shows up in System.in, you've lost. You can't get back to á from that.

@Holger System.out.charset() does not exist. Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in, System.console().charset()) actually solves the reading part, but the output is still incorrect, and if I change the code page (CHCP 65001), then the reading part becomes incorrect (á represented as 0). Furthermore in Eclipse this result in Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.io.Console.charset()" because the return value of "java.lang.System.console()" is null.

It seems like CHCP65001 ruins the reading part, but without it the output is incorrect.

Well, as I said, System.out.charset() requires Java 18 or newer whilst System.console().charset() will not work in Eclipse. It has all been said even before you tried. When you change the codepage, you need a Java version capable of detecting the codepage. Which brings you back to square one as Java 18 is the first doing this flawlessly. That’s why it also introduces System.out.charset() to find out which encoding the console uses (which may be different from the default native encoding). But when you set the codepage explicitly, you can pass exactly that encoding to new Scanner(…).

@Holger Thank you! I was accidentally used Java 17. With Java 18+ this is almost the solution! Using a laptop with Hungarian settings it works fine, both on the console and Eclipse. On a laptop of English settings it works fine with Eclipse. Rhe reading from command line and comparing works also fine, some accented letters (like á, é, í etc.) are also displayed correctly in command line, however, there are a few which do not show up correctly: ő, ű, Á, Í, Ő, Ú and Ű. And if I change the code page to 65001, then encoding the input accented letters become 0.

@Holger Your answer is almost perfect. There is a small addition which I found meanwhile: the code page of the command line should be changed to 852, i.e. chcp 852. This results correct output of accented letters, the accents in the input is not ruined, and the solution works fine in both Eclipse and command line. Would you like to compose this as main answer (instead of a comment), so that I can accept it as solution? (If so, please include the 852 code page in the answer.)

Before code page change the bytes of Sándor is this That's certainly not CP852

Also it doesn't tally with this report from you: Also, what does this print? 53 c3 a1 6e 64 6f 72 in answer to my first question

@g00se The bytes of the correctAnswer having value Sándor are 53 c3 a1 6e 64 6f 72 with the default UTF-8 settings.

That code I got you to run will output the default encoding unless something goes badly wrong. You should of course run it before making any changes in encoding configuration

“You may have heard about 'unicode normalization' which does not fix this.”  It doesn’t?  It did for me.  Passing both of those strings through Normalizer.normalize with NFKD as the second argument made them equal.

@VGR normalizers can make 'e + accent the previous letter' be equal to é. It cannot make ν equal v or ∨, or ！be equal to !, or e look like е and so forth. It also isn't going to make Mueller be equal to Müller.

@rzwitserloot That is true.  But is it relevant to this question?

@VGR The question is about "I ended up with a 0 / I ended up with the replacement character" which normalization obviously cannot fix, so I'm not sure why you brought up NKBD. You say 'it works for me' - in what way? How do you know you have the same windows OS setup as everybody who could ask this question?

I was only addressing your general statement that normalization can’t make "IJsselmeer" and "Ĳsselmeer" equivalent.  I was surprised you mentioned normalization at all, as it doesn’t really apply to this question at all in my opinion.

@VGR It's one of a million answers to "2 strings that were intended to be equal are not, and I think it is somehow unicode related". But, yeah, in a drive to be complete, that was probably too far a bridge to cross.
